# Running Development On Apache2 Server with Local SSL

Tags: apache, ssl

Atttempting to develop a website on Apache2 with local SSL.  I cannot get the website to open as `https` and get the warning that the site is not private.  Verified mod_ssl is enabled and below is my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerAdmin me@somewhere.com
   ServerName example.com
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php|py)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
   DocumentRoot /applications/xxxx/website
   <Directory />
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
   <Directory /applications/xxxx/website>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog /applications/xxxx/logs/xxxx.error.log
   LogLevel warn
   CustomLog /applications/xxxx/logs/xxxx.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```